# How to know if ios delegate is released

Tags: ios, architecture, exc-bad-access, delegation, nsobject

I use delegation extensively for VIEW - CONTROL - MODEL structure. Usually, CONTROL & MODEL objects are retained during the running of the app, causing little issues.

However, VIEW objects, which are often the instances of `UIViewController`, are allocated and release numerous times.

Setting `nil` to the delegate object who is assigned with dynamic `UIViewController` instance, when it's being deallocated, is one way I know how to avoid EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

However, even if I always use:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(communityModel:finishedDeletingComment:)]) {
    [delegate communityModel:self finishedDeletingComment:succeeded];
}
```

it's not perfect for preventing error. If different VIEW objects are sharing one or limited number of delegates of a CONTROL object, it's always prone to cause delegates to be replaced by another unintentionally, causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Is there better way to manage delegates, to know if it's really available at the moment of calling delegate methods?

I doubt if my usual way of setting properties for delegate should be changed. I use this way to set delegate's properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ControlDelegate> delegate;
```

Am I going to the right track doubting about property setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declare delegates as `assign` properties when my object (which will use delegate) is a member of delegate or member of member of delegate etc. In this case `retain` property will lead to memory leak.
Elsewhere I do not see the reasons to not retains delegate. If it's acceptable for you - try to declare your property as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ControlDelegate> delegate;
```